# How to make a two-way table from a dataset? Transpose a single row?

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe.

```
Foo    Gender    Binary    Zip    Frequency
1      Male      0         Yes    4
3      Female    1         No     6
1      Female    0         No     7
2      Male      0         Yes    1
2      Male      0         No     3
```

How do I make Foo into a Row variable and keep the rest of the variables as columns? I want the output to look like this:

```
    Gender    Binary    Zip    Frequency
Foo
1    Male       0       Yes        4
     Female     0       No         7
2    Male       0       Yes        1
     Male       0       No         3
3    Female     1       No         6
```

I know the transpose function but I think it applies to the entire matrix or dataframe. Is there a way to transpose a single column so that it's a row variable? I'm also aware of reshape and dcast but I don't know how to get it so that it looks like the one above.

```
>> dput(head(df1))
>> c(0, 0, 35, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "row variable" here? What is the exact structure of your desired output?

Comment: @agstudy yeah. MrFlick, I think the structure of my desired output is a table or matrix dataframe.

Comment: @cooldood3490 Please add `dput(head(df1))` to your question.

Comment: @agstudy I added it to my question

Comment: @cooldood3490 Impossible that you df1 is what you show in your question..here df1 is just a vector , your str tell us that it is a table , in your question you say it is a data.frame ...I can't help you.

Answer (score 3):

I really don't understand what do you want to do. For me you just try to sort your table according to Foo column then remove duplicated values for smart printing.

```
xx <- dat[order(dat$Foo),]
xx$Foo[duplicated(xx$Foo)] <- ""

Foo Gender Binary Zip Frequency
A 1   Male   0      Yes 4        
C     Female 0      No  7        
D 2   Male   0      Yes 1        
E     Male   0      No  3        
B 3   Female 1      No  6
```

#### Edit :

In case you have a table object , you can't use `$ operator`, you should `[` for subsetting

```
## you should use as.table to get good formatting
xx <- as.table(xx[order(xx[,"Foo"]),])
xx[duplicated(xx[,"Foo"]),"Foo"] <- ""
xx
  Foo Gender Binary Zip Frequency
1   1   Male      0 Yes         4
3     Female      0  No         7
4   2   Male      0 Yes         1
5       Male      0  No         3
2   3 Female      1  No         6
```

where xx is :

```
structure(c("1", "3", "1", "2", "2", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "4", "6", "7", "1", "3"), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), c("Foo", "Gender", "Binary", 
    "Zip", "Frequency")), class = "table")
```

Comment: When I do `xx <- dat[order(dat$Foo),]` on the my dataframe (I think it's a table) I get the following error: `Error in df1$Rank : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` How do I fix this?

Comment: `table [1:4, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2] 0 0 35 0 0 0 17 0 118 154 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
  ..$ Rank   : chr [1:4] "1st" "2nd" "3rd" "4rd"
  ..$ Gender     : chr [1:2] "Male" "Female"
  ..$ Binary     : chr [1:2] "Yes" "No"
  ..$ Zipped: chr [1:2] "Yes" "No"`

Comment: for the dataset I'm applying this to, now I'm getting the error `incorrect number of dimensions`. It's progress though

Comment: =/ okay no prob. I gave you an vote for trying to help. I'll keep trying to get it to work and solve the problem @akrun I am interested in solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing the expected outcome, I did the following. mydf is your sample data.

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %>%
    arrange(Foo) %>%
    group_by(Foo) %>%
    mutate(new = row_number(Foo)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(Foo = ifelse(new != 1, "", Foo)) %>%
    select(-new)

Source: local data frame [5 x 5]

  Foo Gender Binary Zip Frequency
1   1   Male      0 Yes         4
2     Female      0  No         7
3   2   Male      0 Yes         1
4       Male      0  No         3
5   3 Female      1  No         6
```